# Django Admin 404 - Media URLs?

Tags: django

I understand that this question has been asked previously, however every solution i have found does not fix my problem.

In "admin" when saving a model it returns 404. Any model without an image upload is fine.

> ```
> Raised by:    django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
> ```

My settings.py contains:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#and, in processors:
'django.template.context_processors.media',
```

and my urls.py contains:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # urls
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the model:

```
coat_of_arms = models.ImageField(upload_to='coat_of_arms', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: can you upload the view and the template for the form you created to upload the image.

Comment: It's directly via the admin panel. I have not created custom views or forms.

Answer (score 0):

in your main project url you need to put location inside the url pattern. you could do this

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Those settings are made aren't they?

urlpatterns = [
    # urls
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)